# array of actions ["delete", "cancel"] and rights determined by string "01"

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, typescript

The back end responds an array of actions ["delete", "cancel", "edit", "clickbutton"] etc.
Another string is returned which contains for example "1001". It represents the rights to do the actions.

So in this example we can only delete and click button.

What is the fastest way to get the right for an action?

(In the front end I will need to get the corresponding right quickly for each component.)

I was thinking of looping the actions array until there is for example the cancel label, then get the index and with  the index get the corresponding 0 or 1. Is there a faster  way ?

Thanks

Comment: If you're returning an array of actions and a string of rights, why don't you just return the array of actions that they have rights to from the server instead of doing that logic on the front end where it can be changed anyway?

Comment: It is an entreprise app and they dont planned to modify the current behaviour . As a front end developer, they want to migrate the front on javascript and i should adapt with the fast way possible

Comment: typescript is not javascript and should therfore not be tagged with both javascript and typescript unless it has something to do with transpiling `let worksInVanilla: boolean = false;`

Comment: `["delete", "cancel", "edit", "clickbutton"].reduce((r,c,i) => "1001"[i] === "1" ? r.concat(c) : r, []);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
var actions = ["delete", "cancel", "edit", "clickbutton"];
var rights = "1001";

function hasRight(right){
    return rights[actions.indexOf(right)] === "1";
}

console.log("delete",      hasRight("delete"));
console.log("cancel",      hasRight("cancel"));
console.log("edit",        hasRight("edit"));
console.log("clickbutton", hasRight("clickbutton"));
console.log("foobar",      hasRight("foobar")); // returns "false" for invalid actions.
```

`actions.indexOf(right)` returns the position of the specified `right` in the `actions` array.

That position is then used to get the "bit" at the right position, from the "rights" string.

Then, that "bit" is compared to `"1"`, to check if the you have the current right.

---

To store all your rights in an easy to access object:

```js
var actions = ["delete", "cancel", "edit", "clickbutton"];
var rights = "1001";
var currentRights = {};

function hasRight(right){
    return rights[actions.indexOf(right)] === "1";
}

for(var i = 0; i < actions.length; i++){
    currentRights[actions[i]] = hasRight(actions[i]);
}

console.log(currentRights);
console.log(currentRights["delete"]);
console.log(currentRights["foobar"]); // Still falsy
```

Comment: thanks. And do you think I should do your function on every action at the beginning and store an object with property the action and a right property. Or should I apply your function every time I need ?

Comment: Storing the "rights" in an object, when you first load them, would be faster in the long run. That said, I don't think the performance difference will be noticeable, even if you access these rights 10k times on a single page.

Answer (score 1):

well you could do something like this:

```js
var actions = ["delete", "cancel", "edit", "clickbutton"];
var mask = "1001";

var getActions = function (actions, flags) {
  flags = flags.split("");
  return actions.filter(function (action, i) {
    return flags[i] === "1"
  });
};

var allowedActions = getActions(actions, mask);

console.log(allowedActions);

console.log("can delete?", allowedActions.includes("delete"));
```

but since i don't know what exactly you want to do i cannot provide more than this.

what this does so far is simple:

getActions is a function you only need to run once.
it just returns the permissions that are allowed (if you run it, the first console output)
it takes the actions as array aswell as your masking string.

using .includes on that array will tell you if you have a particular permission or not.

in addition you could even turn it into an object:

```js
var actions = ["delete", "cancel", "edit", "clickbutton"];
var mask = "1001";

var getActions = function (actions, flags) {
  flags = flags.split("");
  var obj = {};
  actions.forEach(function (action, i) {
    obj[action] = flags[i] === "1";
  });
  return obj;
};

actions = getActions(actions, mask);

console.log(actions);

console.log("can delete?", actions.delete);
console.log("can cancel?", actions.cancel);
console.log("can foo?", actions.foo);
```

Comment: Don't use `map` just to iterate an array., You don't need to split the string to access individual characters. The `filter`/`includes` combination means you have to loop twice. And just a personal preference: since `delete` is a JS keyword, I prefer: `actions['delete']`

Comment: keywords don't apply to object members and can safely be used, there is no fundamental difference in running map over for though forEach would be the better choice in this case, splitting a string sure is too much but it keeps sticking with me since good old IE did not have .indexOf() on strings. so ye. personal preference.

Comment: i'd prefer using `[...flags]` though. but ye. thats probably not working in all browsers where this shall run.